# Office Word Task Pane Add-in - Is it possible to save a file locally?

Tags: office-js

I have tried to save a file locally when running the command in taskpane.js.

This example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/word/get-the-whole-document-from-an-add-in-for-word?tabs=powerpoint it only sends the file to another server.

I want to do something similar where the file is grabbed, but it is instead saved locally. I cannot find any method in the SDK in the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.document?view=word-js-preview

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that what you are asking is not possible. An Office add-in is a web application and it faces the same security restrictions as a web application. Web apps cannot access the local file system (except for a few limited exceptions, like cookies). So, you can't save a file locally in the way that you have in mind.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback! Do you have any idea what this might do then? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.document?view=word-js-1.5#word-word-document-save-member(2)

I have tried to use that "save as" but I can't seem to get it to do anything

Comment: It will save changes to the current document. But you can't open a document from the local file system in an add-in, which as I understand it is what you want to do. The user would have to open a document and then invoke the add-in. The add-in could then save it.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible for Windows Office and Office on the web, except when using Firefox. You can use [`window.showSaveFilePicker()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API#writing_to_files).
I haven't tried hooking it up with `Office.context.document.getFileAsync`, but I can't see why it wouldn't work.